# Query on iPod apps

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

A silly question, is building an iPhone app different from building a iTouch/iPod app, in terms of technology, programming language?

regards,
darkie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're the same code-wise.  Any app that can run on an iPod touch can also run on an iPhone, and vice versa (unless the developer specifically restricts the distribution of his app to only one or the other, but that's not done at compile time; that's done when submitting the app to the app store).  The only thing that's different is that the iPod touch doesn't have some of the features that iPhones do (like a camera).

Answer (score 1):

Just the hardware differences - you need to make sure that your app deals with devices that don't have a camera, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another functionality not available on iPod Touch is vibrate. A few apps targeting both got rejected for assuming such support on iPod Touch.