# Can the same app be used for both Iphone and Ipod Touch?

Tags: iphone

can a single application be used in both iphone and ipod touch > or we have to build them seperately ? Are there IPod only applications ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query on iPod apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152161/query-on-ipod-apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all work for both unless there are specific features that only the iPhone has, but everything the iPod can do, the iPhone can. You have to check for the specific features while programming to make sure it'll work on the iPod if you have optional features that will only work on the iPhone.

- Examples:

  -GPS

  -Camera(for 1-3rd gen iPod Touch)

  -3G network, although most of the time apps will default to wi-fi if
     you're connected

  -Gyroscope(for the new iPhone 4 and ipod Touch 4g models only)

  -Some apps are intensive so the programmer might restrict it to the
     newer 1ghz cpu that only the iPhone 4 and iPod touch 4g have now

  -Retina Display check(again only iPhone 4 and iPod touch 4g)

  -Multitasking(iOS 4 only on certain models)

  -Microphone(iPhone and iPod Touch 4G, earlier iPod Touch models need headset)

  -Bluetooth(iPod Touch 1G and 2G don't have it) 
      Although some 2G models later enabled bluetooth with OS 3.0

Comment: The camera and 3G connection (obviously) are a couple of iPhone only features.

Comment: ok, how dissimalar are latest ipod touch and iphone 4 ? not much i think.

Comment: I edited my response, that should be most if not all the differences.